# Kernel of matrix with identity as submatrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, manifolds

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$ be a $C^\infty$ map and let $X=\text{graph}f$, i.e. $$X=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^k\mid y=f(x)\}.$$ What is the tangent space to $X$ at $(a,f(a))$?

If I computed correctly, this comes down to finding the kernel of the $k\times (n+k)$ matrix $\begin{bmatrix}-Df(a) & I_k \end{bmatrix},$ where $I_k$ is the $k\times k$ identity.

What is the kernel of this matrix? Can we find it explicitly?

Comment: Yes, for instance you may use the relation $\begin{bmatrix}-Df(a)&I_k\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}I_n\\Df(a)\end{bmatrix}=0$.

Comment: @emeu So the kernel is the column space of your second matrix, right?

Comment: Yes, the relation proves that the column space of the second matrix is included in the kernel, but a dimension argument actually shows that they are equal (the dimension of the kernel cannot be more than $n$).

Comment: In other words, the tangent space is $\{(h,Df_a(h))|h\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$ where $Df_a$ is the derivative of $f$ in $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the map $F:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^{n+k}$ defined by $F(x)=(x,f(x))$. It is smooth, with the derivative at $a$ being the linear operator 
$$DF_a h = (h, Df_a h)$$ 
The range of the derivative describes the   tangent space: 
$$T_{F(a)}X=\{(h,Df_a(h)) : h\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$$ 
as [loup blanc](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600702/kernel-of-matrix-with-identity-as-submatrix#comment1273200_600702) said in a comment.